# How can I access the :locals hash from inside a partial instead of the local variables with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Apart from being a good idea or not, I would like to know how to access the :locals hash from inside a partial instead of the local variables with the same name?

I'm attempting to try to explore a potentially more efficient approach to a pattern I often find myself in involving default partial values:

```
:locals => { :opts => {:myvar => @myvar}}
```

Then inside partial:

```
opts.reverse_merge!(defaults)
```

It would be a lot cleaner to write (especially when opts get more numerous):

```
:locals => { :myvar => @myvar}
```

Then inside partial:

```
opts => defaults.merge(local_hash)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access everything that came in on the `locals` hash to a rendered partial by calling `local_assigns`. I think you'll find, however, that there is more coming in than you'd expect (as Rails creates a few local assigns of its own for your convenience). So your approach may need to adjust... but this is how you'd do it.